# Azure: Script or Command to delete instance and all its associated resources (disks, network interface)

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

I am trying to find a way to delete an Instance in azure and all its associated resources. But I don't see any straightforward approach to accomplish it. I am using `az vm delete -g resourcegroup -n myinstancename--yes` command which currently only deletes instances. In my scenario, I **can't** use powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing ,I created a VM with **`1 NIC, 1 Public IP and 2 Data disks`**.

[image]

Then, I used the below `az CLI` script :

```
$osDisk =  (az vm show --resource-group ansumantest --name ansumantest --query "storageProfile.osDisk.name" --output tsv)
$datadisks = (az vm show --resource-group ansumantest --name ansumantest --query "storageProfile.dataDisks[].name" --output tsv)
$nics= (az vm show --resource-group ansumantest --name ansumantest --query "networkProfile.networkInterfaces[].id" --output tsv)
foreach ($nic in $nics){
   $publicIps=az network nic show --id $nic --query "ipConfigurations[].publicIpAddress.id" --output tsv
}
az vm delete --resource-group ansumantest --name ansumantest --yes
if ($osDisk) { 
   az disk show --resource-group ansumantest --name $osDisk --yes
}
foreach ($datadisk in $Datadisks){
  az disk delete --resource-group ansumantest --name $datadisk --yes
}
foreach ($nic in $nics){
  az network nic delete --id $nic
}
foreach ($publicIp in $publicIps){
  az network public-ip delete --id $publicIp
}
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

---

## OR

You can directly delete all the resources while the running the **VM delete Command** as well but there are some **Prerequisites** for this method i.e. While **creating the VM** using CLI you have to configure couple of features like below :

As per **[Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_create)** in `az vm create` section:

1. **[--os-disk-delete-option {Delete, Detach}]**

> Specify the behavior of
> the managed disk when the VM gets deleted i.e whether the managed
> disk is deleted or detached.
> accepted values: Delete, Detach

2. **[--data-disk-delete-option]**

> Specify whether data disk should be deleted or detached upon VM deletion.

3. **[--nic-delete-option]**

> Specify what happens to the network interface when the VM is
> deleted. Use a singular value to apply on all resources, or use = to
> configure the delete behavior for individual resources. Possible
> options are Delete and Detach.

If the above 3 are configured to delete while creating the VM then , when you run the `az vm delete` it defaults to delete these resources when the VM is to be deleted.

**Reference:**

[Github Support](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/17846)

Comment: @thanks AnsumanBal-MT